# Non-alternating chromatic factors?

Tags: graph-theory, chromatic-polynomial

It is well-known that the coefficients of a chromatic polynomial alternate in sign.  But is it possible for a chromatic polynomial to have a factor (over $\mathbb{Q}$) with coefficients which do not alternate?

Comment: I have looked quite hard for factors that do not alternate without success... it would be nice if the claim were true but I cannot see any way of approaching it.

Answer (score 2):

Factor over what field?

Over $\mathbb{R}$, this is false. The roots of chromatic polynomials are dense in the complex plane, a [result of Sokal](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=206953). So, let $f(t)$ be a chromatic polynomial which has a root in the left half plane, $f(-a+bi)=0$. Then $t^2+(2a)t+(a^2+b^2)$ is a factor of $f(t)$.